# 'Int' is not identical to 'UInt8' in closure

Tags: swift, int, closures, uint8t

I am trying to create a closure that keeps a reference to the local variable of the outer function and I keep getting this ambigious error int is not identical to unint8. It does not make sense to me because there no arrays involved here. There are also no `UInt8s` involved here too.

```
func increment(n:Int)-> ()->Int {
    var i = 0
    var incrementByN = {
        () -> Int in
        i += n
    }
    return incrementByN
}
var inner = increment(4)
inner()
inner()
inner()
```

I found that I can fix this by returning `i` after `i+=n`. I thought that `i+=n` would return on it's own but apparently it does not.

Comment: FWIW, it can be fixed by explicitly returning `i` (instead of the value of `+=` which may be throwing things off here): `i+=n; return i;`

Comment: @Thilo You wrote that at the exact time I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the UInt8 is about, but it seems that `+=` does not have a value.

```
var i = 1;
let x = i += 3;  // now x is of type ()
```

You can explicitly return the new value of `i`:

```
var incrementByN = {
    () -> Int in
    i += n
    return i
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`+=` for `(Int, Int)` is declared as

```
func +=(inout lhs: Int, rhs: Int)
```

It returns nothing.

I don't know why `UInt8` involves, though.
Maybe, it's because `func +=(inout lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8)` is the **last one** of `func +=(...)` declarations.